# Use a different RewriteRule depending on whether or not QueryStrings are used?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

On my blog (which I'm in the process of redesigning for a more efficient way of displaying content), I have a RewriteRule setup to handle a simple redirection from

`http://new.kn3rdmeister.com/blog.php`

to

`http://new.kn3rdmeister.com/category/blog/` (and it works backwards too)

In the .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^blog\.php$ /category/blog/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^category/blog/?$ blog.php [L]
...
```

That works just dandy. Now what I would like to do is rewrite

`/blog.php?pagenum=x`

to

`/category/blog/page/x/`

In the .htaccess:

```
...
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST|HEAD)\ blog\.php\?pagenum=([0-9]*)\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^blog\.php$ /category/blog/page/%2/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^category/blog/page/([0-9]+)/$ blog.php [L]
```

All I can get to work is the first rule, which ends up working, but it displays the QueryStrings rather than the oh-so-clean page directories, like so...

`/blog.php?pagenum=2` for example equals

`/category/blog/?pagenum=2`

I hope I've made my question clear enough :/ If you need anything clarified, please ask and I'll update my post. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Add a question mark to the end of your target in your RewriteRule:

```
RewriteRule ^blog\.php$ /category/blog/page/%2/? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I still get `/blog/content/?pagenum=x`

Comment: @kn3rdmeister The rule you posted doesn't go to `/blog/content/`, it goes to `/category/blog/page/`. Obviously, you need to add a `?` at the rule for that as well, in fact, for all of the ones you don't want a query string when redirecting.

Comment: Oh yeah, goodness :/ I'm tired right now :D It's all right in the .htaccess, but still doesn't redirect to `/category/blog/page/x'. I just posted the wrong thing... *embarassed